# Find the most frequent items among the arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays in my code.

```
array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'guava', 'grapes'];
array2 = ['apple', 'jackfruits', 'banana', 'malta'];
array3 = ['banana', 'grapes, 'apple'];
```

Now i want to get one array from high frequency to low frequency repetation in arrays.

like the result would be

```
array_result = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'orange', 'malta', 'jackfrouits'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'guava', 'grapes'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'jackfruits', 'banana', 'malta'];
$array3 = ['banana', 'grapes', 'apple'];

$arr = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);
$count_arr = array_count_values($arr);
arsort($count_arr);
print_r($count_arr);
print_r(array_keys($count_arr));
```

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) states  Counts all the values of an array.
[arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) states Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association.
[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) states Merge one or more arrays.
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) states Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array.

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e19b886a21f135b90648a1ca390a2af206c2958).

Give it a try this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'guava', 'grapes'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'jackfruits', 'banana', 'malta'];
$array3 = ['banana', 'grapes', 'apple'];
// Merge them and count all the values
$array_counts = array_count_values(array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3));
// Reverse order by counts
arsort($array_counts);
// Make an array based on the keys
$array_result = array_keys($array_counts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'guava', 'grapes'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'jackfruits', 'banana', 'malta'];
$array3 = ['banana', 'grapes', 'apple'];

$arr = array_count_values(explode(',',implode(',',array_values($array1)).",".implode(',',array_values($array2)).",".implode(',',array_values($array3))));
arsort($arr);
print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `array_count_values` like this:

```
 print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

More info in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php